# Anomalous dates when converting from class factor to class date

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time-series

I have a bit of a problem with plotting dates on a line plot in ggplot. When I read in the data from a .csv file, the dates look fine (e.g. 26/10/2016) but they are factors. I am using the dd-mm-yyyy format here. When I convert to date using as.Date(), however, the year becomes 2020 in all observations and is inverted (e.g. 2020/10/26). As a result, the dates are completely useless on the x-axis when plotted as the year is given as simply 20.

[image]

I have tried various combinations of "%d/%m/%y" within the as.Date() wrapper but to no avail.

Here is a sample of the data I am using before converting the date variable to a date object.

```
date <- as.factor(c("26/10/2016","15/06/2016","19/06/2016","22/06/2016","23/06/2016"))

clinton <- c(45.8,40.0,41.0,41.7,42.0)

trump <- c(40.4,35.3,36.0,36.8,37.0)

johnson <- c(5.8,5.3,6.5,6.5,7.0)

stein <- c(1.8,3.3,4.0,4.2,4.3)

df <-  data.frame(date,clinton,trump,johnson,stein)
head(df)
```

My code for the plot once I have converted date to class date:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date,"%d/%m/%y")

df_long <- melt(df,id="date")  # convert to long format


ggplot(data=df_long,aes(x=date,y=value,colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue","red","yellow","green")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,45,5)) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d/%m/%Y")) +
  ylab("")
```

Oddly, with this example data, the year is plotted as 2020 not 20 like in my original data? Without going back to LibreOffice to modify all of the dates to something like dd-mm-yy, is there a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 4 digits years (year with century), so you need to use `%Y` instead of `%y` in `as.Date`.  The first is for 4 digit years, the second is for 2 digit years.  See the help page for `strptime` for all the abbreviations and definitions.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you.